# Antiderivative of a branch function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

> Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} $, $ f(x) = e^{x} $ for $ x \leq 0 $ and $ ax+b $ for $ x > 0 $. I want to determine the real numbers $ a $ and $ b $ for which $ f $ admits antiderivatives.

I took a plausible antiderivative $ F(x) = e^{x} + c $ for $ x < 0 $, $ F(0) = \alpha $ and $ a \frac{x^{2}}{2} + bx + d $ for $ x > 0 $ and using the fact that $ F $ must be first continuous and then differentiable, I showed that $ b = 1 $.

This is easy to see as from continuity we must have that $ d = \alpha = c+1 $.

Then, since F is clearly differentiable on $ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $ if we impose the condition that the left and right derivatives at $ 0 $ of $ F $ to be equal so we must have:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x <0 }\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x > 0 }\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}$$

Thus:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x <0 }\frac{e^{x}+c-c-1}{x} =  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x > 0 }\frac{a\frac{x^{2}}{2}+bx+c+1-c-1}{x} $$

Which gives us $ b = 1 $.

My question is then, does this suffice? Can $ a $ be chosen arbitrarily such that $ f $ has antiderivatives as long as $ b = 1 $. It would seem that the function $ F(X) = e^{x}+c $ for $ x \leq 0 $ and $ F(x) = a\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x+c+1 $ for $ x > 0 $ for $ c \in \mathbb{R} $ does indeed satisfy the necessary conditions.

Is it maybe that I am missing something here? I would appreciate any comments. Thank you!

Comment: Seems fine to me. In practice, you can impose extra conditions, like existence of the 2nd derivative, to get a constraint on $a$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $f$ admits an antiderivative iff $f$ is a derivative of some function. Thus, by Darboux theorem, $f$ has to have an intermediate value property. For $f$ of the given form this is equivalent to $b=1$ as you got as well. Then, independently of the choice of $a$, $f$ is continuous and has an antiderivative by (one of) the Fundamental Theorem(s) of Calculus.